# Google Analytics Event and Goal Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I am stuck at point and don't know how to go ahead. The scenario is -

I am tracking the visitors flow and registration on my website. I have also created different funnels and goals for the same. 
Note - after coming to my website, there are 3 other ways through which a visitor can register on my website  and I have created separate funnels for those flows.

Secondly, all registered users(through all funnels) are getting approved by the admin at the back end. I am separately able to capture that data in an event and hence created a goal for the number of approved users but still don't know through which funnel they registered and got approved.

My question is " How can i track and show the numbers in GA that the approved user is coming from a particular funnel/flow. For example - 4 approved user came through funnel A, 6 came through funnel B and 2 came through C."

Is it possible to show in GA?

Comment: Have you tried a Custom Report?

Comment: Thanks Bianca. I tried using custom dimension and custom report to capture the number of approved users coming back to my website but the data is not matching with the data that my technical team is capturing at their end.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom segment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3124493?hl=en
which includes users that have reached goal.

Then you can get Acquisition reports for this segment.